# How to find the name of the person from the list

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

How to return a person's name when we search for a hobby and it should return empty when there are no matching hobbies.

Comment: There is no context to this question. One can assume you have a collection of `Person` objects which describe a `Hobby` property which you can filter the list by with `FirstOrDefault`. However we can't know this, we can only assume. Please provide details.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to skin this cat. Using Linq is probably the most standard.

The operation you want to do is to select the Key of the dictionary where the value (the array of hobbies) contains the string "Yoga"

```
val keys = hobbies.Where(keyvalue => keyvalue.contains("Yoga")).Select(keyvalue => keyvalue.key);
```

now you have a sequence of keys where one of the hobbies is Yoga.

If there is only a single one, and it's an error if there are more, get CC with  `keys.Single()`.

If there could be zero or more, and you just want an arbitrary one, you want `keys.FirstOrDefault()` which returns null if there isn't one.

In between you have `SingleOrDefault()` for 0 or 1, or `First()` for 1 or more select an arbitrary one.